# jqgrid, alert with arror after failet add record to database

Tags: jqgrid, alert

it's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var grid = $("#list");
$(function(){ 
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid({
url:'grid.php',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['ID sprzętu','Kod sprzętu', 'Właściciel','Konfiguracja'],
colModel :[ 
  {name:'SprzetID', index:'SprzetID', width:90}, 
  {name:'Kod', index:'Kod', width:120, editable: true}, 
  {name:'Wlasciciel', index:'Wlasciciel', width:200, align:'left', editable: true}, 
  {name:'Konfiguracja', index:'Konfiguracja', width:400, align:'left', editable: true}, 
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
sortname: 'SprzetID',
sortorder: 'asc',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
caption: 'Lista sprzętu'
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
      {add: true, edit: true, del: true, search: true}, //options
      {width:400, }, // edit options
      {width:400,closeAfterAdd: true, url:'add.php'}, // add options
      {reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // del options
      {width:600} // search options
      );
});
```

All is great, when adding record to database is correctly, but when for example field "Kod" is duplicate (it's unique field), record can't be add to database... and isn't. I want to display alert with error message, but I can't find in documentation how to do it... I gues,I should use "afterSubmit", but how... I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. In add parameters I added code:

```
afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
              if(response.responseText != ""){
                  return [false, response.responseText];

              }else{
                  return [true,"Ok"];
              }}
```